Open Telemetry Tail sampling - available attributes
How can i determine what attributes are available to apply tail sampling to for open telemetry data.
Is there some documentation that i can reference or logs i can check to know exactly what attributes i can select rather than it being guess work?
Specially looking for documentation around http and jdbc filtering
I have tried using the attributes as i see them in elastic but that doesnt seem to work
ie a key of transaction.name or url.full didnt work but a key of http.url did work but that isnt available in elastic.

Have a look at the debug exporter, that will dump the data into the logs of the collector. Keep in mind the different between resource attributes and Span attributes. There isn't a page we can produce, since the available attributes are the ones your code and the instrumentation libraries add.

I am not aware of any documentation released so far officially(if there is any, would love to get the link).
You can refer this readme: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/tailsamplingprocessor/README.md
I hope this helps!
